# How to get one list in python out of a list in for loop

Tags: python

I have a list of li, I want to get int of this list as a x and to be able to use x[1], x[2], x[3] in another function. but I am not able to print them out of for loop.

```
li =[]
li =[['0', '5', '8', '15', '20'], ['0', '6', '7', '14', '19'], ['0', '8', '10', '12', '18']]
for i in li:
    x=[]
    for j in i:
        m=[int(j)for j in (i)]
    x.append(m)
    print(x)
```

I expect to use these list as a x[1], x[2], x[3] out of this for loop.

```
x[1]=[0, 5, 8, 15, 20]
x[2]=[0, 6, 7, 14, 19]
x[3]=[0, 8, 10, 12, 18]
```

The output is:

```
[[0, 5, 8, 15, 20]]
[[0, 6, 7, 14, 19]]
[[0, 8, 10, 12, 18]]
```

Comment: Define `x` *outside* the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to create the list and map function to cast strings to integers:

```
x = [list(map(int, element)) for element in li]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Navid.

Comment: My pleasure @Sevda

Answer (score 0):

```
li =[]
li =[['0', '5', '8', '15', '20'], ['0', '6', '7', '14', '19'], ['0', '8', '10', '12', '18']]
x={}
count = 0
for i in li:
    count += 1
    x[count] = i
print(x)
#output: {1: ['0', '5', '8', '15', '20'], 2: ['0', '6', '7', '14', '19'], 3: ['0', '8', #`enter code here`'10', '12', '18']}

This way you can use
#x[1]=[0, 5, 8, 15, 20]
#x[2]=[0, 6, 7, 14, 19]
#x[3]=[0, 8, 10, 12, 18]


for i in x.keys():
    print(x[i])
```